# How can I implement ScheduleAtFixedDelay function using Quartz?

Tags: timer, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I know how to use Quartz for some basic requirements.
But if I want to mimic the ScheduleAtFixedRate which can make the next task starts with a fixed delay after last task finished, how can I do that? 
I can only find examples about making job start in a fixed rate.
Or do you have any alternative ways to implement such a function?

job1
|
 execute for 3s
|
 delay for 2s
|
job2
|
 execute for 1s
|
 delay for 2s
|
job3
|
 execute for 5s
|
 delay for 2s
|
job4
.
.
.

I want to implement this using Quartz

```
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(...);
```